# Node js + express + session

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, express

I was figuring out how to create a session after somebody logs in. I would like to have a function that creates the session, a function to check if a session is active(if somebody loged in) and a way to close it.

I searched a lot but nothing seemed to work, probably it's my error. Here is my code so far.

```
    var   express   = require('express')
    , exp       = express()
    , fs        = require('fs')
    , pub       = 'public/'
    , port      = 80
    , log       = fs.createWriteStream('./web.log', {flags: 'w'});;

exp.configure(function(){
    exp.use(express.static(__dirname + '/' + pub));
    exp.use(express.logger({stream: log})); 
    exp.use(express.bodyParser());
    exp.use(express.cookieParser());
    exp.use(express.session({secret:'sea-anemone'}));
});

exp.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(pub + 'index.html');
});

exp.post('/', function(req, res){
    var u = req.param('username', null);
    var p = req.param('password', null);
    If (u == "admin" && p == "pass"){
        /* call function to create session */
    }
});

console.log("Server started")
exp.listen(port);
```

Comment: This is really well documented so it feels like you just want us to write your code for you.

Comment: Agree with Pickles but if you want to checkout the place i got started with this check this http://www.hacksparrow.com/sessions-in-express-js-node-js-web-framework.html

Comment: Well I don't have a DB with users so a lot of auth func won't work, and I've been trying for 3 days now and got nothing working. Yes I would like an example that works in my case...

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookie sessions in Express.js. [This gist should help you get started.](https://gist.github.com/1491756)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) or [EveryAuth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth) rather than writing your own auth/session code?

Comment: Yes i tried both, but i have no DB with users there are only 5 users.
And i didn't succeed in implementing those in my code. I only got headaches.